# night light per monitor

Tags: gnome, 20.04, night-light

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and I'm loving night light. 
But I'm in a dual-monitor setup, and sometimes I'm watching a movie in a screen and browsing the web in the second screen. Yes, it's kind of insane, I don't focus very well, but I like it.

So is it possible to disable night light only in my movie-monitor ?